# TypeError exception not being caught

Tags: python, python-2.x

Why is this `TypeError` not being caught by exception ?

```
>>> op=None
>>> try:
...     val = op['one']
... except KeyError, TypeError:
...     val = "one"
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enclose the list of exceptions in parens/brackets:

```
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    #  ^                   ^
    val = "one"
```

Comment: @Krish This is definitely the solution to the error, so could you elaborate more on *it didn't help*?

Comment: `>>> op=None
>>> try:
...     val = op['one']
... except (KeyError, TypeError):
...    val = "one"
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> `

Comment: Interesting, the solution works for me. Did you save your file?

Comment: no, I am trying it in the console, just like I pasted above, mnie is Python 2.7.6

Comment: When I save and execute, it works as expected, thank you. but wondering why it didn't work when I tried in console.

Comment: @bernie Are you sure this works? It shouldn't. Did you type KeyError and TypeError in the other order?

Comment: @bernie I'm really confused by that. Do you know why it's working? The [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#except) I've linked in my answer very much suggests that it shouldn't.

Comment: @jpaugh Why not? It is in the format that the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) explains it

Comment: @Wondercricket Because I forgot that the parens makes the above a tuple, not just an over-specified expression, and because it's (IMO) insane to allow tuples there. [Artyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939163/typeerror-exception-not-being-caught/46939642?noredirect=1#comment80826512_46939642) explained this really well, though.

Comment: @Wondercricket Actually, the parens are *not* necessary for the tuple! Only to resolve the grammar's ambiguity, which is the very same thing I was tripping over. I ❤ Python, but not today.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 does not allow specifying multiple exceptions in the same `except` clause this way. You might expect the `,` to create a tuple of Exceptions (which would be valid, as [bernie demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939179/712526)), but that's not what happens.

Looking at the [language spec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#except), we have

```
"except" [expression [("as" | ",") identifier]] ":"
```

where the comma is interchangeable with `as`.

In other words, the following two except clauses are equivalent

```
except KeyError, e:
    print "We got a key error!"
except KeyError as e:
    print "We got a key error!"
```

This catches a `KeyError`, and gives it a name of `e`. So, in your code, you're catching a `KeyError` and giving it a *name* of `TypeError`.

---

To overcome this ambiguity in Python's grammar, and specify multiple exceptions (kudos to Artyr and Downshift for explaining this), you must use parentheses to force it to be interpreted as a single *expression* (to be interpreted as a tuple of exceptions), rather than AS *expression COMMA identifier*.

```
except (KeyError, TypeError), e:
    pass
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    pass
```

Again, the above two expressions are equivalent, and assign the caught exception to the variable `e`. Notably, the form with a comma [was removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except), making the language grammar a bit less confusing!

```
"except" [expression ["as" identifier]] ":"
```

Comment: > For an except clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object, *or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.*

Comment: but python2 *does* allow for multiple exceptions "An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple" `except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):` https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions In the language spec that's what the comma allows for. You can test it here: https://repl.it/NOBd

Comment: @Artyer thanks for explaining that. I was loosing my sanity a bit.

Comment: @downshift Thank you, too! Although, now that I'm seeing double, I'm starting to feel a little loopy, again. ;-)